# Link collection several times

Tags: linked-data

I often create my objects in a separate file, and I link the object in my new file using `File > Link` and then I browser until the collection containing my object. Unfortunately, I can't repeat this twice to add a second copy of the object, as nothing will get added then... Any idea how I could get two instances of a collection created in another file?

**EDIT**

I'm lost, now it seems to work... So I need to understand why sometimes it works and sometimes it fails...

Comment: Hi :). You can also Shift+(D)uplicate the linked instance. Might be faster than linking manually the same asset.

Comment: @JachymMichal I was not able to do that, I was getting some errors. But I can't reproduce anymore, I'll maybe give more information or fill a bug if I manage to reproduce it.